# How to take quotients of ideals for polynomial rings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Suppose I have field $k$, element $a \in k$ and I want to find the quotient:
$$k[x]/(x-a)$$
The way I've always thought about quotients is that we are 'setting $(x-a) = 0$' in some sense, and so in this particular case it seems that we can 'achieve' this goal by setting $x = a$ (i.e. for every polynomial, evaluating it at $x=a$).

Is this a valid way of finding the quotient? And can this method be generalised; i.e. if I want to find the quotient

$$k[x]/(f(x))$$

for arbitrary polynomial $f(x)$ with roots $r_1,...,r_n$, it seems like a 'natural way to extend this idea' would be to send each polynomial $g(x) \mapsto g(r_1)g(r_2)...g(r_n)$ (or maybe this is completely misguided?)

Comment: The answer would be yes, it is a valid way, and yes, the method can be generalised. It can be explained by saying that the quotient $k[x]/(x-a)$ there is an equivalence relation given by $f(x)\sim g(x)$ iff $f(x)-g(x)\in \langle x-a\rangle$, so in particular, $(x-a)\sim 0$. This equivalence relation becomes the equality in the quotient $k[x]/(x-a)$.

Comment: You need to be a little bit more careful in case your polynomial $f$ is irreducible over $k$.